# problems with ambiguity in uima ruta

Tags: uima, ambiguity, ruta

I have several complex rules that fail when confronted by ambiguous concepts:
Here's a simple example:

```
ANNOTATIONLIST  temp;
DECLARE TestPerson(uima.tcas.Annotation   concept);
DECLARE TestPlace(uima.tcas.Annotation   concept);
DECLARE TestSubject(uima.tcas.Annotation   concept, uima.cas.FSArray  children, String kind);
DECLARE TestModifier(uima.tcas.Annotation   concept);
DECLARE TestBE;
DECLARE TestAdj;
"bank"  ->  TestPerson;
"bank"  -> TestPlace;
"nice"   -> TestAdj;
"was" -> TestBE;
p:TestPlace{-> CREATE(TestSubject,"concept"=p, "children"=p, "kind"="place")};
p:TestPerson{-> CREATE(TestSubject,"concept"=p, "children"=p, "kind"="person")};
a:TestAdj{-> CREATE(TestModifier,"concept"=a)};

DECLARE TestRelation (uima.tcas.Annotation arg1 ,uima.tcas.Annotation arg2,String kind);

(p:TestSubject TestBE? m:TestModifier)
{ ->
            child:CREATE(TestRelation, "kind"="BE", "arg1"=p.concept, "arg2"=m.concept),
                LOG("child1:" + m.ct),
                LOG("parent1:" + p.ct),
                ASSIGN(temp, p.children),  // what we're stuck with
                ADD(temp, child),
                FILL(TestSubject, "children"=temp)
};
```

For the input sentence "The bank was nice". only ONE of the bank meanings gets 2 children:

```
<RutaMain:TestPerson xmi:id="2555" sofa="37" begin="4" end="8"/>
  <RutaMain:TestPlace xmi:id="2560" sofa="37" begin="4" end="8"/>
  <RutaMain:TestAdj xmi:id="2565" sofa="37" begin="13" end="17"/>
  <RutaMain:TestBE xmi:id="2569" sofa="37" begin="9" end="12"/>
  <RutaMain:TestSubject xmi:id="2577" sofa="37" begin="4" end="8" concept="2560" children="2555 2657" kind="place"/>
  <RutaMain:TestSubject xmi:id="2591" sofa="37" begin="4" end="8" concept="2555" children="2555" kind="person"/>
  <RutaMain:TestModifier xmi:id="2605" sofa="37" begin="13" end="17" concept="2565"/>
  <RutaMain:TestRelation xmi:id="2622" sofa="37" begin="4" end="17" arg1="2560" arg2="2565" kind="BE"/>
  <RutaMain:TestRelation xmi:id="2657" sofa="37" begin="4" end="17" arg1="2555" arg2="2565" kind="BE"/>
```

I am using Ruta 2.7.0 but the problems with ambiguity are worse with 2.8.1 (in other cases)

Comment: I tested in 2.8.1 and the results are the same

Comment: P.S. Is this the right forms for posting ruta issues or should I be using another?

Comment: I am no sure what the desired output should be. Each TestSubject should contain one TestPerson/TestPlace and one TestRelation?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend upgrading to Ruta 3.2.0

```
(p:TestSubject TestBE? m:TestModifier)
{ -> child:CREATE(TestRelation, "kind"="BE", "arg1"=p.concept, "arg2"=m.concept),
                ASSIGN(temp, p.children), 
                ADD(temp, child),
                p.children=temp
};
```

[image: Resulting annotations]

In your rule, `FILL(TestSubject, "children"=temp)` matches on the first TestSubject at this position in the index, but not that one matched by the rule element before.

(I tested the rule with the current Ruta version)